# htaccess - remove trailing slash for one specific page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a WP site, all working great. I then have a stand alone landing page called "landing-page.php" and this is in the root directory.

I need to remove the .php and the trailing slash in order for the page to load. I only want to remove the trailing slash for this specific page. I cannot change the directory where this page is saved as I have ad campaigns that have been configured with /landing-page/ so I cannot go change these without re-approval etc

I have the following code which kinda works BUT... I cannot access /wp-admin.

So I need the rules only to apply to this landing page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^landing-page$ landing-page.php [L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please help... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to get rid of this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and change the next line to:

```
RewriteRule ^landing-page/?$ landing-page.php [L]
```

?

Not sure what the problem is, but the first line is probably the problem because it's matching *everything* with a trailing slash. But if you want to canonicalize the trailing slash, just make it match `landing-page` specifically:

```
RewriteRule ^landing-page/$ /landing-page [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your top 2 rules with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(landing-page)/$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^landing-page$ landing-page.php [L,NC]
```